# Would KafkaTemplate open multiple connections to a broker if I produce multiple messages from the same application?

Tags: spring-kafka

We are using spring-kafka-2.2.7.RELEASE to produce and consume messages.Now my question is, Would KafkaTemplate open multiple connections to a broker if I produce multiple messages from the same application? If yes, how can we control the no of connections?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends; if you are not using transactions, a single shared producer is used by default (as recommended by the Kafka javadocs) for all operations.

The actual behavior is controlled by the `DefaultKafkaProducerFactory` used by the template, not the template itself.

With 2.3.x+, you can create a producer per thread:

```
/**
 * Set to true to create a producer per thread instead of singleton that is shared by
 * all clients. Clients <b>must</b> call {@link #closeThreadBoundProducer()} to
 * physically close the producer when it is no longer needed. These producers will not
 * be closed by {@link #destroy()} or {@link #reset()}.
 * @param producerPerThread true for a producer per thread.
 * @since 2.3
 * @see #closeThreadBoundProducer()
 */
public void setProducerPerThread(boolean producerPerThread) {
    this.producerPerThread = producerPerThread;
    this.threadBoundProducers = new ThreadLocal<>();
}
```

When you are using transactions, either a pool of producers is used (for producer-initiated transactions) or a producer per `group/topic/partition` is usually used for consumer-initiated transactions (for proper zombie fencing operation).

Comment: Thanks @Gary for the response. Does it mean, if I'm not using transactions, it would open only one TCP connection since it's a shared producer?

Comment: In general, yes, but it's a bit more complicated than that; you may end up with a connection to each broker in a cluster, depending on how partitions are distributed across cluster members.

Comment: Got it, Thanks for the exaplanation